# How to pass the Document context in Xpages while calling an Agent?

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, xpages-ssjs

How to pass the Document context in Xpages while calling an Agent? In Xpage, I am in need of calling a java agent with documentcontext from my Xpage, And also I am in need of passing my current document as a parameter...

In Lotuscript we can do it as easily without saving the current document, but in Xpage I am using the following code., document1 is a current document.

```
var agent=database.getAgent("AgentName");
agent.runWithDocumentContext(currentDocument.getDocument());
```

This code I am not able to get the values of my current document's items, but if I will use the following code,

```
var agent=database.getAgent("AgentName");
document1.save();
agent.runWithDocumentContext(currentDocument.getDocument());
```

I can get the item value of the current document... But I do not want to save the document, without saving the document I need to get the item value of item.

Please give any nice solution for that...

Comment: should it not be? : agent.runWithDocumentContext(document1);

Comment: Yes That throws an Error... After that I have tried document1.getDocument() method

Comment: Aha, I did't see your re-edit. You cannot call background agent on the document, that has not been saved before on the web since the agent runs on server and your document is opened in frontend website. Server doesn't know, your document even exists...

Comment: what triggers your code? button?

Comment: did you try getDocument(true), what passes changed fields from datasource to backend document?

Comment: getDocument(true) thanks all it is working...  Thanks Frantisek Kossuth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

agent.runWithDocumentContext(currentDocument.getDocument(true)). This will put all the new values inside the backend doc, so it works the same way as lotusscript does. Also, if you need to have the currentdocument computed with the notes form, set the 'computewithnotesform' property of the datasource to 'onload' or 'both'.

Comment: Ferry it is very nice., I can get my item's value

Answer (score 2):

Since when there can be more then one document source on the xPage, I use ParameterDocID...

```
var id = document1.getDocument().getNoteID();
var agent = database.getAgent("MyAgent");
agent.run(id)
```

and in the agent...

```
Call GetDocument(agent.ParameterDocID)
```

...

```
Public Sub GetDocument(DocID As String)
On Error GoTo eh

Set Doc = Db.GetDocumentByID(DocID)

es:
Exit Sub
eh:
Resume es
End Sub
```