# Communicate WQS-agent with XPage - possible?

Tags: xpages, lotusscript

I've been pondering this for a while, but can't think of a solution.

I have an XPage where I upload a file. The datasource has a WQS LotusScript agent that performs some processing on the file.

How can I communicate any result from this LotusScript agent back to the XPage?

Thanks!

/J

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632910/how-to-pass-the-document-context-in-xpages-while-calling-an-agent

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked for. I don't have a problem passing the documentContext. I wish to return information FROM LotusScript TO XPages, not the other way around.

Comment: I guess that's jjtbsomhorst's point, use the documentContext for that. From the WQS agent write the result to the documentContext and read it again from the XPage after the WQS has finished.

Comment: Indeed thimo that is what I meant. As of 8.5.2 (i think ) you can use in memory documents in agents. This way you dont need to create a document, save that document, run your agent. Update your document in the agent. REad the document again in xpage and check if everything did go well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the in-memory document to pass to the agent and you get it back. See [my example](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SF7AH) or its [bean version](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SF7AH). However I would challenge the benefits of talking to an agent. You pay every call with a 0.5-3sec performance penalty spinning up and shutting down the LotusScript engine.

Taking this into account your break even for sitting down and transform your agent into a Java class is "closer that it appears".

Comment: "You pay every call with a 0.5-3sec performance penalty spinning up and shutting down the LotusScript engine." Have things gotten worse since R5? When I last measured the time to submit a form, run a simple QS LotusScript agent and report back to browser, the whole round-trip took 0.1-0.2 sec.

Comment: Ah... you don't have servers under heavy load then :-) - But still it is 100-200ms time for 1-2ms computation :-)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm aware it's patched patches, but the speed isn't critical here.

Comment: Hmm..LotusScript engine loading gets slow under heavy load but nothing else does :-). If I remember correctly it was about 0.1 sec more when I added the agent as you said. My users have never complained about 100ms delay :-) But when I started using XPages they complained all the time about the response time.